# Validating multiple forms, of an undetermined number, in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I have a complex ordering page, which creates an undetermined number of registration forms, using ng-repeat. It can be one form, and it can also be 10.

The submission process takes the scope objects from all forms, processes it, and then "submits" the order. I do not use ng-submit or anything similar, being that it's actually more than one form.

The question is, whether i can somehow iterate through all objects on the scope created by the forms, and check for the $valid property(a form named "myForm" would create a $scope.myForm.$valid).

In a standard one-form page, i just perform this check on form submission. But how would you do it for multiple forms of an undetermined number? It seems to me that AngularJs just creates a new object on the scope for each form, in accordance with the form name...

Any ideas?

Comment: Would you mind sharing some code?

Comment: You can nest forms in AngularJS, using ng-form, and validation state should propagate up to the containing form, which should allow you to use ng-submit. Apologies, no links or anything as I'm just on my phone.

Comment: Interesting idea natwallbank..I've never heard of it. Problem is, that I've already written a very untidy and hard-to-edit code(i'm new to AngularJs and fairly new to programming), so it would take too much time, which i dont have, to reorganize it. Maybe it's possible to somehow "push" each form object into an array, and then iterate through it?